# Jquery select all elements with an innerHTML that starts with a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I know you can use :contains to get elements who's innerHTML contains a certain string, but how can I get the elements whose innerHTML starts with a string?

Comment: Do you mean all elements whose firstChild is a text node?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using a filter function you can filter based on any criteria that you'd like:

```
var spans = $("span").filter(function(idx) {
   return this.innerHTML.indexOf(myString) == 0;
});
```

Comment: No need to wrap things :) `this.innerHTML` works, and is much less expensive as well.

Answer (score 21):

I know this is old, but if anyone is looking for a better answer, jQuery since v1.1.4 has a [":contains("text")" selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

**Example HTML:**

```
<p>Please reply above this line...</p>
```

**Example jQuery selects above HTML:**

```
$('p:contains("Please reply above this line")');
```

Comment: I love finding these easier (on the eyes, anyway) solutions in older posts.  This one is semantically easier to understand.

Comment: The question states that the OP is aware of `:contains` but needs something to just filter based on the start of the innerHTML string.  Therefore @joshperry has the correct solution.

Comment: Simply the best and the cleanest. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "JavaScript" src = "jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "JavaScript">
var elems;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").each(function(){
        var content = $(this).html();
        if (content.match(/asdf/)){
            alert(content);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>asdfaowhguiwehgiuh</div>
<div>asdfaowhguiwehgiuh</div>
<div>fdsaaowhguiwehgiuh</div>
<div>fdsaaowhguiwehgiuh</div>
<div>fdsaaowhguiwehgiuh</div>
<div>asdfaowhguiwehgiuh</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In order to find whether it's in the content at all..if you want the first few characters you should split the content on those characters and test just it.

Answer (score 1):

The filter method will let you compare an element's content, and then you can do whatever you like (in this case, I've done `addClass('selected')`).

```
$('p').filter(function() {
  var searchString = 'Blue';
  return ($(this).html().substring(0, searchString.length) == searchString);
}).addClass('selected');
```

Demo:

http://jsbin.com/ironi/2