# jquery selector start with content

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery select all elements with an innerHTML that starts with a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631199/jquery-select-all-elements-with-an-innerhtml-that-starts-with-a-string)

my code:

```
<a href="#">Prefix today is monday</a>
<a href="#">Prefix today is wednesday</a>
<a href="#">other links</a>
```

is there a jquery selector can select the elements by the content that start with "Prefix" ?

i know there is a contains selector like this:

```
$("a:contains('Prefix')")
```

but it's "contains", is there a "StartWith" content selector?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631199/jquery-select-all-elements-with-an-innerhtml-that-starts-with-a-string ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("a:contains('Prefix')").filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML.indexOf('Prefix') == 0;
})
```

You could also check against the text, if you don't want HTML interfering:

```
$("a:contains('Prefix')").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf('Prefix') == 0;
})
```