# Conditional jquery element selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table:

```
<table id="codexpl">
<tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Columna</th>
    <th>Relative</th>
    <th>Isso</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>http://stackoverflow.com/</td>
    <td>Is</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Coloumn</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>this</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>http://stackoverflow.com/</td>
    <td>not equals</td>
    <td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>the</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>real</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Coloumn</td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to select only the tds that have urls in them and change their contents with

```
   $("td").each(function(){
          $('<div class="box"><iframe src="' + this.href + '" width = "500px" height = "500px"></iframe></div>').insertAfter(this);
         });
```

I've selected them before using jquery that looks like:

```
$('td').hover( function() {
          var contents = $( this ).html() ;
           if (contents.match("^http")) {
```

I'm wondering if you do something like this pseudocode:

```
 $('td' WHERE innerhtml=="^http"){....
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery select all elements with an innerHTML that starts with a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631199/jquery-select-all-elements-with-an-innerhtml-that-starts-with-a-string)

Comment: You could use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), but that doesn't quite give you what you want since it'll search the whole string.

Comment: Will the pattern of the URL be consistent? Always start with "http"? Or do you need to match more complex URL patterns?

Comment: Yes  - Always start with "http"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

going off what Stryner said in the comments: with `:contains()`

something like this? (also note, its not html friendly if you insert divs into tds)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td:contains(http)').each(function() {
        $(this).html('THIS WAS A LINK');
    });
});
```

```css
td {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="codexpl">
<tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Columna</th>
    <th>Relative</th>
    <th>Isso</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>http://stackoverflow.com/</td>
    <td>Is</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Coloumn</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>this</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>http://stackoverasdfasdfflow.com/</td>
    <td>not equals</td>
    <td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>the</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>real</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Coloumn</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter TDs maybe.

```
$("TD").filter(function(el) {
  return $(el).text().indexOf("http") !== -1;
});
```

Way of finding link is not the most sophisticated one, you can think of better, like regexp etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using the jQuery filter you can minimize the selected elements and than just iterate through matching results.

```
$("td").filter(function(idx) {
  return $(this).text().indexOf("http") !== -1;
}).each(function(){

    var contents = $(this).html() ;
    $('<div class="box"><iframe src="' + contents + '" width = "500px" height = "200px"></iframe></div>').appendTo($(this));
});
```

See working example here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/3w10tfou/1/